# pm2 - Startup script for non-root user permission denied

Tags: node.js, root, pm2

I just installed pm2 (on Debian 9) and I need to run NodeJS server of few users. Every user have own NodeJS server what I need to run under them. Not under root.

For example I have user "user1":

- I can control pm2 normally
- This command on user1 for enabling startup scripts:
  `pm2 startup`
- Then I copypaste outputed command to root and execute...
- Startup script for given user is now created

pm2 still works on user1, but after restart I cannot control pm2 and Iam getting this error:
`[PM2][ERROR] Permission denied, to give access to current user:
$ sudo chown user1:user1 /home/user1/.pm2/rpc.sock /home/user1/.pm2/pub.sock`

If I execute this command on root, I can then again control pm2 on user1, but all NodeJS servers are executed as root!!

I need to 'grant' permissions every restart..

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself why it not work. My user names are with dot (domain.com) and systemd not recognised this as valid user name... Because that service started under root.

Quick fix is to find auto-generated service in systemd and replace user name with user id found by `id -u <user>`

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if there are any risk with the following method, but it did solve same issue I was facing.

```
1- open new terminal (fresh, without sudo permission)
2- sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user1/.pm2 (gives permission to the .pm2 folder)
3- pm2 start index.js (Note that there is no sudo here)
4- pm2 save
5- pm2 startup
6- Restart your computer and check pm2 monit
7- It should list your index process now. If not, try from 1-5, 8, and then 6.
8- paste the command listed in step 5
```

Comment: @Max I flagged your comment

Answer (score 2):

You probably started the pm2 tasks using root. So check the system processes that you are using by:

```
sudo systemctl -a
```

If you find a unit name pm2-root, that is the one that you need to remove. Run the command `sudo systemctl stop` pm2-root and `sudo systemctl disable pm2-root`. Then use your user name to start the process.

Make sure you are using **pm2-sammy** with **sammy** as your user name.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `sudo pm2 <command>`